# Swift Decoding JSON from Amadeus

Tags: swift, decodable, jsondecoder

I have a problem with decoding JSON from API. 
I get JSON:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "count": 1,
    "links": {
      "self": "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/reference-data/locations?subType=AIRPORT&keyword=barcel&sort=analytics.travelers.score&view=LIGHT&page%5Boffset%5D=0&page%5Blimit%5D=10"
    }
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "location",
      "subType": "AIRPORT",
      "name": "AIRPORT",
      "detailedName": "BARCELONA/ES:AIRPORT",
      "id": "ABCN",
      "self": {
        "href": "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/reference-data/locations/ABCN",
        "methods": [
          "GET"
        ]
      },
      "iataCode": "BCN",
      "address": {
        "cityName": "BARCELONA",
        "countryName": "SPAIN"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My code looks like this:

```
struct Airport: Decodable {
    let meta: MetaAirport
    let data: AirportInfo
}
struct Address: Decodable{
    let countryName: String
    let cityName: String
}

struct AirportInfo: Decodable{

    let address: Address
    let subType: String
    let id: String
    let type: String
     let detailedName: String
     let name: String
     let iataCode: String

}

struct MetaAirport : Decodable{
    let count: Int
    let links: Links
}

struct Links : Decodable{
    let info: String

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
           case info = "self"
       }
}
```

I'm trying to decode json using JSONDecoder on an AirportInfo object

```
              do {
                let airport = try JSONDecoder().decode(Airport.self, from: data!)
                    print(airport.data.name)
                }
                catch let err {
                    print(err)
                }
```

I get an error

> typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Now - after the edit - the situation is completely different. Please **read** the error and the JSON. `data` is clearly an array.

Comment: I edit my code. I know thet  I have to do it at the Airport structure
let data: [AirportInfo]

Comment: The error tells you to change your definition of the `data` property to `let data: [AirportInfo]`

Answer (score 0):

In json data, address is a object. Change your code:

```
let address: [Address] -> let address: Address
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have edited your question from the original, so it feels hard to correctly identify at a given moment in time where the issue is.

**However**, Codable is great and one easy way for you to work through it is by constructing your object little by little. There is no requirement for an object to identically represent your JSON **IF** you make things optional. So when debugging this kind of issues, make different properties optional and see what got parsed. This would allow you to identify little by little where you're doing things wrong, without causing crashes and keeping the correctly formatted parts.

Also, pro tip: If you plan to keep this code for anything more than 1 week, stop using force unwrapping `!` and get used to handle optionals correctly. Otherwise this is a hard habit to stop and others will hate the code you've created ;)

Comment: @oyasumi, please see the updated answer to your problem. I think learning how to use Codable generally will have more value than trying to find a specific error in an actively developed structure

Answer (score 0):

Your Model should be like that to parse

```
struct DataModel: Codable {
    let meta: Meta?
    let data: [Datum]?
}

struct Datum: Codable {
    let type, subType, name, detailedName: String?
    let id: String?
    let datumSelf: SelfClass?
    let iataCode: String?
    let address: Address?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type, subType, name, detailedName, id
        case datumSelf = "self"
        case iataCode, address
    }
}

struct Address: Codable {
    let cityName, countryName: String?
}

struct SelfClass: Codable {
    let href: String?
    let methods: [String]?
}

struct Meta: Codable {
    let count: Int?
    let links: Links?
}

struct Links: Codable {
    let linksSelf: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case linksSelf = "self"
    }
}
```